# Ruby: Iterating Calculations

Tags: ruby, loops

Say that I have calculated something like body mass index that is pretty straightforward and looks like this:

```
def body_mass_index(weight, height)
    body_mass_index = weight / (height * height)
    if body_mass_index < 18.5
        puts "underweight" 
    elsif body_mass_index >= 18.5 && body_mass_index < 25.0
        puts "normal"
    elsif body_mass_index >= 25.0 && body_mass_index < 30.0 
        puts "overweight"
    else 
        puts "obese"
    end
end
```

Now say that I want to iterate over a list of heights and weights, possibly in the form of an array. How do I combine these two things in some code? I want to say something like:

```
[height, weight], [height, weight], height, weight].each do { |bmi| height, weight }
```

but it does not work.

Comment: Can you please write your code in the indented manner ? Hint: Use `ctrl+k` to have the section to write the code. It is hard to understand your question in this manner

Comment: code has been edited. thank you for the suggestion

Comment: Do you mean: [[height, weight], [height, weight], [height, weight]].each { |bmi| body_mass_index(bmi[0], bmi[0]) }

Comment: If if works then I mean that!

Comment: What is your loop supposed to do?

Answer (score 1):

For ruby iterate, there are two styles:

```
[....].each do |i|

end

[...].each { |i| ...}
```

they are the same, you can use anyone.

Please have a try:

```
[[height, weight], 
 [height, weight], 
 [height, weight],
].each {|bmi| body_mass_index(bmi[1], bmi[0]) }
```

Comment: It works!     i used:    .each do |bmi| body_mass_index(bmi[0], bmi[0])
  end

Comment: I am a beginner and I feel as if i ALMOST can do things like this. I am not sure why your solution works. Would I be able to generalize this example to other calculated things like temperature conversions, currency conversions, etc?

Comment: It is same, you also can use `each { ...  }`

Comment: @liuzxc you're passing the arguments in the wrong order

Answer (score 1):

Now that you've solved the syntax issue, the missing part of your original:

```
[[height, weight], [height, weight], [height, weight]].each do { |bmi| height, weight }
```

Is that it doesn't pass the height and weight values to the body_mass_index method.

This part of liuzxc's solution

```
.each {|bmi| body_mass_index(bmi[1], bmi[0]) }
```

indexes each of the [height, weight] arrays at 1 (bmi[1]) and at 0 (bmi[0]) and passes the values along to the body_mass_index method

To understand the difference you could try running it with the above referenced part of liuzxc's solution replaced with

```
.each {|bmi| puts "weight is #{bmi[1]} height is #{bmi[0]}"}
```